# Variable initialization Error happen when compiling below java programme

Tags: java, variables, initialization

Running this code I got the compiler error situation. Why does it happen?

```java
import java.util.*;
class Example {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input an integer : ");
    int num=input.nextInt();
    int y;
    if(num>100){
      y=200;
    }
    if(num<100){
      y=200;
    }
    if(num==100){
      y=200;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answers the reason why you are getting this error is that:

> "The local variable y may not have been initialized"

`int y = 0` should help you in this situation.

Also, I suggest to use **try with resources**, because in recent versions of Java you will also get an error message:

> "Resource leak: 'input' is never closed"

So your final result should look similar to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Input an integer : ");
        int num=input.nextInt();
        int y = 0;
        if(num>100){
            y=200;
        }
        if(num<100){
            y=200;
        }
        if(num==100){
            y=200;
        }
        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

Comment: try-with-resources on `System.in` might be a bad idea. Unless you like closed standard input streams.

Answer (score 0):

It's coming because the variable y is not initialized and the compiler thinks if none of the if statement is true then y would remain un-initialized and will not know what to print.

So you need to change

```
int y;
```

to

```
int y=0;
```

Or some other initial value.

Answer (score 0):

***Because We need to initialize every locale variables before using it***,
Lets say none of the condition matched then what should get printed in :

```
System.out.println(y);
```

****Default Value of y** , but compiler highlights that it may be an issue as you wanted some value of Y but its not assigned so check you code.**